# Why python multiprocessing used more CPU and GPU than the specified in-parallel process numbers?

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, gpu

I use python multiprocessing to run 8 pytorch processes in parallel (for 8 CPU Cores and 8 GPU threads). But it consumed 48 CPUs and 24+ GPU threads. Anybody has some clues on how to reduce 48 CPUs and 24+ GPU to 8 CPU Cores and 8 GPU threads?

[htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yn5A.png)

```
(py38) [ec2-user@ip current]$ nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.119.03   Driver Version: 450.119.03   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    28W /  70W |   8050MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1C.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   50C    P0    29W /  70W |   8962MiB / 15109MiB |     11%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1D.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   49C    P0    28W /  70W |   9339MiB / 15109MiB |      9%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   49C    P0    28W /  70W |   9761MiB / 15109MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     30971      C   python                           1167MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     30973      C   python                           1135MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     30974      C   python                           1135MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     30975      C   python                           1135MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     30976      C   python                           1195MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     30977      C   python                           1115MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     30978      C   python                           1163MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30971      C   python                           1259MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30972      C   python                           1241MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30973      C   python                           1295MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30975      C   python                           1273MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30976      C   python                           1287MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30977      C   python                           1269MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     30978      C   python                           1333MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30971      C   python                           1263MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30972      C   python                           1163MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30973      C   python                           1167MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30974      C   python                           1135MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30975      C   python                           1135MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30976      C   python                           1167MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30977      C   python                           1137MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     30978      C   python                           1167MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30971      C   python                           1195MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30972      C   python                           1291MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30973      C   python                           1175MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30974      C   python                           1235MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30975      C   python                           1181MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30976      C   python                           1153MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30977      C   python                           1263MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     30978      C   python                           1263MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the related code snippet:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
for id in id_list:
      p.apply_async(
          evaluate,
          [id],
      )
  
def evaluate(id):
  # PyTorch code ...
```

Comment: Is it possible that your `evaluate` function uses more than one cpu?

Comment: You could set `Pool(processes=1)` and see if you have 8 cpus committed. That would be a good hint that the `evaluate` operation is already being farmed out to the cpus.

Comment: Great hint. I will set Pool(processes=1) to check out.

Comment: @tdelaney Changing to process=1, still fork multiple threads using GPUs. But as below, I resolved the issue in an alternative way instead of digging into memory releasing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of digging into how multiprocess dispatch works and memory releasing, I changed to loop through processes instead of video list, which resolved the problem in a controllable and simpler way. Now I can run 64 parallel processes with exactly specified GPU memory.

```
multiprocess_num = 8
batch_size = int(len(the_list) / multiprocess_num)
for i in range(multiprocess_num):
      sub_list = the_list[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]
      p.apply_async(
          evaluate,
          [sub_list],
      )

def evaluate(sub_list):
  for id in sub_list:
      # PyTorch code ...
```